# What does 'the devil knows what" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, idioms

I am translating a story but I couldn't find the right words for "**the devil knows what**” in these sentences.

Can anyone explain this a little? Maybe that can give me some ideas. This is the full paragraph:

> *And what a liberty on your part, Ivan Ivanovich, offering **the devil knows what** for my rifle. A pig!*
>
> *And why is my pig **the devil knows what** ?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The devil knows what" is the equivalent of "who knows what" (that is, something whose identity or nature is inadequately unspecified), intensified by using "the devil", a curse—which has already been noted as characteristic Ivan Nikiforovich's speech. Paraphrase:

> "It is rude of you to offer me something whose value is completely unknown for my valuable rifle. A pig!"
>
> "Why is the value of my pig unknown?"